# VSCode "Go to file" not finding all files

Tags: visual-studio-code

I am trying to jump to a certain file (CMD + P) in my React project, but VS Code cannot find it even though it is right there. Usually it finds them, but this happens from time-to-time.

I have cleared my "Recently opened files"
I do not have any plugins relating to this.

Any suggestions are appreciated.

[image: no matching results]

Comment: If I had to guess, it is because I have one repo inside another one